# Collision Detection Result Theory?

Tags: collision-detection

To be clear because the title is slightly ambiguous:
I understand that to check for collision detection it's (box.x > otherBox.x && box.x < otherBox.x + otherBox.w) etc.

However I'm curious about things to do after this, how can I sort of keep the player from entering the other object that they're supposedly colliding with without fully stopping them and therefore suspending them from movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would only restrict movement in that direction. In other words, let the player move left only he has not collided with a wall to his left. Let him move right only if there is no wall to his right. This way, if there is a wall on one side, the player can still back away.

You would do this by checking multiple collision points, so instead of box.x, you would check both `box.x+(box.width/2)` `and box.x-(box.width/2)`.